# IOS AFNetworking upload pictures to the server can not resolve base64

Tags: ios, base64, afnetworking

IOS `AFNetworking` upload pictures to the server. The request is successful, But the server can not parse base64 image.

The same request using `ASIHTTPReuqest` framework upload base64 images on the server and parsing is successful. Can you give a suggestion or idea to fix the code with AFNetworking？

**AFNworking request Code:**

```
UIImage *img = [avatar imageWithImageSimple:avatar scaledToSize:EZSIZE(320, 320)];

NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

NSString *strBase64 = [imageData base64String];

NSDictionary * object = @{
           @"firstname"  :@"nameTest",
           @"sex"        :@"male",
           @"user_id"    :@"1234556",
           @"avatar"     :strBase64,
           @"phone"      :@"15899402939"
           };
NSMutableDictionary *parameter = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parameter setObject:@1 forKey:@"app"];

[parameter setObject:@"save_settings" forKey:@"m_action"];

[parameter setObject:[[object JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"m_param"]];

NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                                   URLString:@"http://test..."
                                                                                  parameters:parameter
                                                                   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                                                   } error:nil];



AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

**ASIHttpRequest request code:**

```
UIImage *img = [avatar imageWithImageSimple:avatar scaledToSize:EZSIZE(320, 320)];
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);
NSString *strBase64 = [imageData base64String];

NSDictionary * object = @{
                          @"firstname"  :@"nameTest",
                          @"sex"        :@"male",
                          @"user_id"    :@"1234556",
                          @"avatar"     :strBase64,
                          @"phone"      :@"15899402939"
                          };

NSString *parameter = @"app=1";

parameter = [[parameter stringByAppendingString:@"&m_action="] stringByAppendingString:@"save_settings"];

parameter = [[parameter stringByAppendingString:@"&m_param="] stringByAppendingString:[object JSONRepresentation]];

NSData *data = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(handleRequestEventError:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(parseAndSave:)];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[@([data length]) stringValue]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request appendPostData:data];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

[request setDelegate:self];


[_networkQueue addOperation:request];
```